# fill a simple dynamic array in c++ with vector

Tags: c++, arrays

**i m trying to fill a dynamique 2D array

where i m wrong**

```
#include<vector>
cin<<x;
vector<vector<int>> tab(x);
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{ 
    for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
    {
        cin>>tab[i][j];
    }  
}
```

and also i want to print it to the screen

Comment: given it is actually `cin >> x;` (note the direction of the operator) you have a vector of `x` vectors. these vectors `tab[i]` are empty. To fill them use `push_back()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vector<vector<int>> tab(x)
```

This is only creating a vector for `tab`, but not for the subvectors.

Use:

```
vector<vector<int>> tab(x, vector<int>(x));
```

To populate the subvectors as well.

Be advised that this is not the most efficient way to create matrices.

Answer (score 1):

To create a `std::vector` of `std::vectors` of a given size `x`, use

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> foo(x, std::vector<int>(x));
```

To print it you can use loops:

```
for (std::size_t row{}; row < x; ++row) {
    for (std::size_t col{}; col < x; ++col)
        std::cout foo[row][col] << ' ';
    std::cout.put('\n');
}
```

A more efficient way of having a matrix is to use a `std::vector<int>` of the total size of rows and columns and calculate the index accordingly:

```
std::vector<int> foo(x * x);

// access column `c` at row `r` like
foo[r * x + c];
```

Print it:

```
for(std::size_t i{}; i < x; ++i, std::cout.put('\n'))
    std::copy(foo.begin() + i * x, foo.begin() + (i+1) * x, 
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```